# Loop and render Object array in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, for-loop, angularjs-ng-repeat

[image: typescript object array loop]

In angular we can loop this as below

```
<ul ng-repeat="group in ctrl.timeOptions">
  <li  ng-repeat='option in group' ng-class="{active: option.active}">
    <a  bo-text="option.display"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How to solve this in react Js

I tried many ways

```
_renderRelative() {
    if (this.timeOptions) {
        for (let key in this.timeOptions) {
        if (this.timeOptions.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const group = this.timeOptions[key];
        this._renderGroup(group);
        }}
    }
    return null;
}

    _renderGroup(group: Array<any>) {
        return (
            <ul>{
                group.map((option, i) => {
                    return (<li key={i}>{option.display}</li> );
                })
            }</ul>
        );
    }

 render() 
     {
       this._renderRelative()
     }
```

I find this is hilarious; what is the correct code. Thanks you.

JSON Stringed : `{"0":[{"from":"now-2d","to":"now","display":"Last 2 days","section":0,"active":false},{"from":"now-7d","to":"now","display":"Last 7 days","section":0,"active":false},{"from":"now-30d","to":"now","display":"Last 30 days","section":0,"active":false},{"from":"now-90d","to":"now","display":"Last 90 days","section":0,"active":false},{"from":"now-6M","to":"now","display":"Last 6 months","section":0,"active":false},{"from":"now-1y","to":"now","display":"Last 1 year","section":0,"active":false},{"from":"now-2y","to":"now","display":"Last 2 years","section":0,"active":false},{"from":"now-5y","to":"now","display":"Last 5 years","section":0,"active":false}],"1":[{"from":"now-1d/d","to":"now-1d/d","display":"Yesterday","section":1,"active":false},{"from":"now-2d/d","to":"now-2d/d","display":"Day before yesterday","section":1,"active":false},{"from":"now-7d/d","to":"now-7d/d","display":"This day last week","section":1,"active":false},{"from":"now-1w/w","to":"now-1w/w","display":"Previous week","section":1,"active":false},{"from":"now-1M/M","to":"now-1M/M","display":"Previous month","section":1,"active":false},{"from":"now-1y/y","to":"now-1y/y","display":"Previous year","section":1,"active":false}],"2":[{"from":"now/d","to":"now/d","display":"Today","section":2,"active":false},{"from":"now/d","to":"now","display":"Today so far","section":2,"active":false},{"from":"now/w","to":"now/w","display":"This week","section":2,"active":false},{"from":"now/w","to":"now","display":"This week so far","section":2,"active":false},{"from":"now/M","to":"now/M","display":"This month","section":2,"active":false},{"from":"now/M","to":"now","display":"This month so far","section":2,"active":false},{"from":"now/y","to":"now/y","display":"This year","section":2,"active":false},{"from":"now/y","to":"now","display":"This year so far","section":2,"active":false}],"3":[{"from":"now-5m","to":"now","display":"Last 5 minutes","section":3,"active":false},{"from":"now-15m","to":"now","display":"Last 15 minutes","section":3,"active":false},{"from":"now-30m","to":"now","display":"Last 30 minutes","section":3,"active":false},{"from":"now-1h","to":"now","display":"Last 1 hour","section":3,"active":false},{"from":"now-3h","to":"now","display":"Last 3 hours","section":3,"active":false},{"from":"now-6h","to":"now","display":"Last 6 hours","section":3,"active":false},{"from":"now-12h","to":"now","display":"Last 12 hours","section":3,"active":false},{"from":"now-24h","to":"now","display":"Last 24 hours","section":3,"active":false}]}`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `this._renderOptionList()` should be `this._renderRelative()`:

`_renderRelative()` should return the rendered list.

```
_renderRelative() {
    if (this.timeOptions) {
        //...
        return this._renderGroup(group);
        }
    return null;
}
```

and

```
 render() 
     {
       return this._renderRelative()
     }
```

Comment: Oh sorry that was a typo error. In my code it it is correct. The intention is to clarify, do i need to write all this logic for a 2 line code in angular